# JwtBearerEvents.OnMessageReceived not Called for First Operation Invocation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am using WSO2 as my Identity Provider (IDP).  It is putting the JWT in an header called "X-JWT-Assertion".

To feed this into the ASP.NET Core system, I added an `OnMessageReceived` event.  This allows me to set the `token` to the value supplied in the header.

Here is the code that I have to do that (the key part is the last 3 lines of non-bracket code):

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddJwtBearer(async options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = 
         await wso2Actions.JwtOperations.GetTokenValidationParameters();

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
    {
        // WSO2 sends the JWT in a different field than what is expected.
        // This allows us to feed it in.
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            context.Token = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-JWT-Assertion"];
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
};
```

**This all works perfectly** except for the very first call after the service starts up.  To be clear, every call, except for the first one works exactly as I want it to.  (It puts the token in and updates the `User` object like I need.)

But for the first call, the `OnMessageReceived` is not hit.  And the `User` object in my controller is not setup.

I checked `HttpContext` for that first call, and the "X-JWT-Assertion" header is in the `Request.Headers` list (with the JWT in it).  But, for some reason, the `OnMessageReceived` event is not called for it.

How can I get `OnMessageReceived` to be called for the first invocation of a service operation for my service?

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** I figured out that the issue was `async` `await` in `AddJwtBearer`.  (See my answer below.) That is what I really wanted out of this question.

However, since a bounty cannot be cancled, I will still award the bounty to anyone who can show a way to use `AddJwtBearer` with `async` `await` where it is awaiting an actual `HttpClient` call.  Or show documentation of why `async` `await` is not supposed to be used with `AddJwtBearer`.

Comment: i have put this event handler into bolierplate WebAPI template - seems to pick the handler up from the very first request. can it be that your middleware order is somehow affecting it?

Comment: @timur - See my update at the end of my question.  (It was due to `async` `await` not working well with the call pipeline.)

Comment: it seems that `AddJwtBearer` (and underlying `AuthenticationBuilder.AddSchemeHelper`) do not expect async calls in there - it just adds IConfigureOptions to serices. `OnMessageReceived`, on the other hand - is being awaited on. So I'm wondering if you could potentially make that `OnMessageReceived` lambda async, move your http call into `OnMessageReceived` body and somehow cache results in there?

Comment: @Vaccano did you ever come up with a good solution to solve the actual original problem? Well @timur's solution may work in your case, but not mine. I need to set `options.Authority` to a value obtained asynchronously, but I can't figure out anything better than `options.Authority = Task.Run(() => ...).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, but I'd like a way to avoid wrapping the async code in sync code if possible. I expect not though.

Comment: @jsabrooke - Yes I did.  I was able to get it to work using dependency injection.  That way I could setup the things I needed in advance.  To get it to work you need to register an `IConfigureOptions` like this: `services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>();`  Then make a class (called `ConfigureJwtBearerOptions` in this case) that inherits from `IConfigureNamedOptions<JwtBearerOptions>`.  That class will be used to setup the JwtBearerOptions and will support dependency injection.  Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61186836/16241

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE:
The lambda is an `Action` method.  It does not return anything.  So trying to do asynchrony in it is not possible without it being fire and forget.

Also, this method is invoked on the first call.  So the answer is to call anything you need in this method in advance and cache it.  (However, I have not figured out a non-hack way to use dependency injected items to make this call.)  Then during the first call, this lambda will be called.  At that time you should pull the values you need from cache (thus not slowing down the first call much).

---

This is what I finally figured out.

The lambda for `AddJwtBearer` does not work with `async` `await`.  My call to `await wso2Actions.JwtOperations.GetTokenValidationParameters();` awaits just fine, **but the call pipeline goes on without waiting for `AddJwtBearer` to finish.**

With `async` `await` the call order goes like this:

1. The service starts up (and you wait a while for it all to be happy.)
2. A call is made to the service.
3. `AddJwtBearer` is called.
4. `await wso2Actions.JwtOperations.GetTokenValidationParameters();` is called.
5. `GetTokenValidationParameters()` invokes an `HttpClient` with `await`.
6. The `HttpClient` does an awaited call to get the public signing key of the issuer.
7. While the `HttpClient` is awaiting, the rest of the original call goes through.  No events had been setup yet, so it just goes on with the call pipeline as normal.

   - This is where it "appears to skip" the `OnMessageReceived` event.
8. The `HttpClient` gets the response with the public key.
9. Execution of `AddJwtBearer` continues.
10. The `OnMessageReceived` event is setup.
11. A second call is made to the service
12. Because the event was eventually setup, the event is called.  (`AddJwtBearer` is only called on the first call.)

So, when the await happens (in this case it eventually hits an HttpClient call to get the Issuer Signing Key), the rest of the first call goes through.  Because there was no event setup yet, it does not know to call the handler.

**I changed the lambda of `AddJwtBearer` to not be async and it worked just fine.**

Notes:
Two things seem odd here:

1. I would have thought that `AddJwtBearer` would be called at startup, not on the first call of the service.
2. I would have thought that `AddJwtBearer` would not support an `async` lambda signature if it could not correctly apply the await.

I am not sure if this is a bug or not, but I posted it as one just in case: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20799

Comment: You created the race condition there. You could do step 10 before step 4 to workaround the issue. See my answer :)

Comment: @weichch - unfortunately, the awaited call is needed to be able to decode the JWT. The first call would fail token validation if I ordered the way you show.

Comment: sorry my bad, there was another race condition I wasn't aware of :) Try updated. The original answer was awaiting on the same task for loading parameters, which shouldn't be the one being used by `OnMessageReceived`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your first couple requests cannot trigger `OnMessageReceived` is not because of the `async void` delegate you are using, but the order of how the parameters being loaded and the events being attached.

You attach handlers to events **after** `await`, meaning you created a race condition here, that, if say some request arrives before the `await` is completed, there is no event handler attached to `OnMessageReceived` at all.

To fix this, you should attach event handlers **before** the first `await`. This will guarantee that you always have event handlers attached to `OnMessageReceived`.

Try this code:

```
services.AddAuthentication(opt =>
    {
        // ...
    })
    .AddJwtBearer(async opt =>
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        // Any code before the first await in this delegate can run
        // synchronously, so if you have events to attach for all requests
        // attach handlers before await.
        opt.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            // This method is first event in authentication pipeline
            // we have chance to wait until TokenValidationParameters
            // is loaded.
            OnMessageReceived = async context =>
            {
                // Wait until token validation parameters loaded.
                await tcs.Task;
            }
        };

        // This delegate returns if GetTokenValidationParametersAsync
        // does not complete synchronously 
        try
        {
            opt.TokenValidationParameters = await GetTokenValidationParametersAsync();
        }
        finally
        {
            tcs.TrySetResult(true);
        }

        // Any code here will be executed as continuation of
        // GetTokenValidationParametersAsync and may not 
        // be seen by first couple requests
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` to execute async code in startup. It will block the thread, but it's ok because it only run once and it's in the startup of the application.

However if you don't like to block the thread and insist on using `await` to get the options, you can use `async` `await` in `Program.cs` to get your options and store it in a static class and use it in startup.

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        JwtParameter.TokenValidationParameters = await wso2Actions.JwtOperations.GetTokenValidationParameters();
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}

public static class JwtParameter
{
    public static TokenValidationParameters TokenValidationParameters { get; set; }
}
```