# Jwt Bearer and dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to configure my Jwt Bearer issuer key but, in production usually, I use Azure Key Vault wrapped by a `KeyManager`. 
The `KeyManager` class is configured in Dependency Injection but, in `ConfigureServices` method I cannot use that (obviously), but if I cannot use that I cannot retrieve my key.

My solution at the moment is to build a temporary service provider and use it, but I think is not the state of the art (and I need to create two copies of singletons, not the best).

```c#
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    ServiceProvider sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    IKeyManager keyManager = sp.GetService<KeyManager>();

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = keyManager.GetSecurityKeyFromName("jwt").Result,

        ValidIssuer = "https://api.example.com",
        ValidateIssuer = true
    };

    options.Audience = "https://api.example.com";
    options.Authority = "https://api.example.com";

    options.SaveToken = true;
});
```

Comment: I believe `KeyManager` is your own implementation and you have full control over it. Since `BuildServiceProvider` is an expensive operation, you can think of converting `KeyManager` functionality to an extension method. Also is `keyManager.GetSecurityKeyFromName("jwt").Result` an async method? If that's the case using `.Result` this way is not correct.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and implement `IConfigureNamedOptions<JwtBearerOptions>`:

```
public class ConfigureJwtBearerOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<JwtBearerOptions>
{
    private readonly IKeyManager _keyManager;

    public ConfigureJwtBearerOptions(IKeyManager keyManager)
    {
        _keyManager = keyManager;
    }

    public void Configure(JwtBearerOptions options)
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = _keyManager.GetSecurityKeyFromName("jwt").Result,

            ValidIssuer = "https://api.example.com",
            ValidateIssuer = true
        };

        options.Audience = "https://api.example.com";
        options.Authority = "https://api.example.com";

        options.SaveToken = true;
    }

    public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
    {
        Configure(options);
    }
}
```

In *Startup.cs*:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer();

services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>();
```

Comment: Great thanks for the answer. This shows the beauty of the design of ASP.NET.

Answer (score 12):

So, after more researches, I found this page on Microsoft's docs: [Use DI services to configure options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#use-di-services-to-configure-options-1) (refer also to [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58213990/4142404) that refers to handling dynamically multiple Jwt Issuers).

```c#
services.AddOptions<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.Configure<IKeyManager>((options, keyManager) => {

    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = keyManager.GetSecurityKeyFromName("jwt").Result,

        ValidIssuer = "https://api.example.com",
        ValidateIssuer = true
    };

    options.Audience = "https://api.example.com";
    options.Authority = "https://api.example.com";

    options.SaveToken = true;
});

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer();
```

Comment: Yes, this could work as well. I'd extract configure code into a separate class to keep *Startup.cs* cleaner :)

Comment: This is by far the best answer as realizing this gives you the ability to configure any service options, e.g. `ConfigureApplicationCookie` is a simple `services.AddOptions<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme).Configure<MyDependency>(`.

Comment: I'd been looking for a solution to my "signing-key lifecycle problem" for a long time. (Though my key comes from a different source, and my main issue was disposing it at the right time.) Your solution is elegant and works for me. (Tested with .NET 6.) Thanks!