# how to use dependency injection in IssuerSigningKeyResolver from AddAuthentication.AddJwtBearer

Tags: c#, authentication, dependency-injection, jwt, startup

I want to be able to do a database lookup on the `kid` inside a `IssuerSigningKeyResolver` static method, right now I'm not sure how to properly do this (or if it can be done)

I have found so far two way (they might not be good?)

first one is to have a static instance of a `IServiceScopeFactory` in that static class, next to my custom static method, (set from the startup class) so when my `IssuerSigningKeyResolver` method get executed, I can do a new scope to get my database instance

```
using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var auth = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IAuthServices>();
    .... do something with kid ...
}
```

the second way is something like this when setting up my option in `AddJwtBearer()`;

```
IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, validationParameters) =>
           TokenServices.MyKeyResolver(token, securityToken, kid, validationParameters, builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IAuthServices>())
```

so I'm passing in a new instance with

```
builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IAuthServices>()
```

which I think might not be a good idea? or is it?

my question is mostly, what is the "best practice" way of doing what I want to do? one of my solution or something completely different?

Comment: You can use [DI in Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-di-services-to-configure-options). You still need to create a scope yourself for the database as the `JwtBearerOptions` will be resolved in singleton lifetime. Also note that async operation is impossible in that delegate.

Comment: @weichch do you mind creating a working example in an answer?

Comment: @weichch i found your previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61186836/jwt-bearer-and-dependency-injection i will try this tomorrow, i will close this question as duplicate / already answered when i confirm it work

Comment: @weichch what i did was having the IHttpContextAccessor as DI and using _accessor.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IAuthServices>() to create / access the wanted scoped services, maybe you want to update your other answer with this?

Comment: HttpContexAccessor might not work depends on where the option class was first created. If it was first created during a request then it will work but it will be something like the configuration was created in the context of the request, which might not be ideal depends on your case. Conversely, if the option was first created in a background process, it will fail because there is no HTTP request context. This is why creating a dedicated DI scope for your purpose is IMO a better idea.